# How to run code once per user session in PHP?

Tags: php, session, runonce

Okay, Ive searched around and found how this is supposed to be done. For example, finding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709449/run-php-function-once). However it is not working for me, so I must be doing something wrong, but darned if I know what.

Okay... here is my little code block:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['didit'])) {
        $url = "http://www.mysite.com/clients/vatera.asmx/DoSomething";
        file_get_contents($url);
        $_SESSION['didit'] = true; 
    }
?>
```

The **url** `file_get_contents` is all working perfectly. The only thing not working is the "run once" check. It is running the **url** code EVERY time through the page. It should only run it the first time you hit the page in a session. This block is located immediately following the `<html>` tag in my page.

Some other things I have tried:

```
if(empty($_SESSION['didit']))
if($_SESSION['didit'] != true)
if($_SESSION['didit'] <> true)
```

I also tried moving the line setting the variable to precede the **$url** assignment.

None of these have worked. It continues to run the code EVERY time the page is loaded.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "**following** the `<html>` tag", you mean **before**, right? `session_start()` must come before any output.

Comment: Also make sure you put `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your script too so that PHP gives you any appropriate error or warning messages.

Comment: @simshaun AH! Yes, that was it. I moved it so that the PHP block is the very first thing in the file, and now it works. THANK YOU!!! If you post as an answer, I will accept and give you the rep.

Comment: Good deal. Glad it was a simple solution :). Answer posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "**following** the `<html>` tag", you mean **before**, right?
`session_start()` must come before any output.

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip. I'm an ASP.NET guy, natively, ... I was able to find all I needed for PHP syntax and such, but just missed that one little detail. Works perfect now!

Answer (score 1):

how do you test your code? It will work OK only in real browsers. So, if you using `wget` or `curl` to test - your conditional code will always run b/c wget & curl do not keep session cookies by default.

Also be sure that you do not block cookies in your browser.

Comment: I was testing by running my pages in a browser.